# Use json-time to display some things

Tags: jquery, jsonp

Somebody asked me if it's possible to use the (system) clock to display particulary stuff? I'm using http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json

For example:
When the clock is between monday and thursday then display "message1". When it's between friday and sunday display "message2".

What I have is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  var timezone = "Europe/Berlin";
  $.getJSON("http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json?tz="+timezone+"&callback=?",
    function(data){
      if (data.datetime < ??) { // what do I have to do here?
        alert ("It's monday-thursday in "+timezone);
      } else {
        alert ("It's friday-sunday in "+timezone);
      }
    })
});
  </script>
```

What do I have to do with "??" ? Any help is more then welcome

Comment: If by system clock you mean the actual time on the users computer, you don't need to call an API for that. I would think your server also has the time available, including conversions to different timezones etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want something like this:

```
var timezone = "Europe/Berlin";
$.getJSON("http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json?tz=" + timezone + "&callback=?", function(data) {
    var day = new Date(data.datetime).getDay();
    if (day > 0 && day < 4) {   // days start with 0 (Sunday)
        alert("It's monday-thursday in " + timezone);
    } else {
        alert("It's friday-sunday in " + timezone);
    }
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/sXbUv/